# Android NDK overflows dalvik JNI local reference table

Tags: android, java-native-interface, dalvik, android-ndk

I have the following problem, from c++ I send huge string[] to java. huge = at most 20 rows; 
I am doing the following

```
jint jtype = 2;
jstring emptyString = env->NewStringUTF("");
jobjectArray data = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(7, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), emptyString);

env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,0,env->NewStringUTF(item->get_id().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,1,env->NewStringUTF(item->get_number().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,2,env->NewStringUTF(item->get_fullname().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,3,env->NewStringUTF(item->get_mf().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,4,env->NewStringUTF(item->get_dob().c_str());
env->CallVoidMethod(dao, jsaveItem, data, jtype);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   jstring string = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(data, i);
   env->DeleteLocalRef(string);
}
env->DeleteLocalRef(emptyString);
env->DeleteLocalRef(data);
env->DeleteLocalRef(dao);
```

this is happening in a loop so I am doing it for every object I want to save in the database, so as you can imagine, it happends lots of times.

So I am considerate of the VM and delete the local refs of every string I create, but still I get  :

```
 ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)
Last 10 entries in JNI local reference table:
  502: 0x40552880 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  503: 0x405528b8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  504: 0x4051f8d0 cls=Ljava/lang/Class; 'Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao;' (212 bytes)
  505: 0x4052eb38 cls=Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao; (12 bytes)
  506: 0x4051f8d0 cls=Ljava/lang/Class; 'Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao;' (212 bytes)
  507: 0x4052eb38 cls=Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao; (12 bytes)
  508: 0x4051f8d0 cls=Ljava/lang/Class; 'Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao;' (212 bytes)
  509: 0x4052eb38 cls=Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao; (12 bytes)
  510: 0x4051f8d0 cls=Ljava/lang/Class; 'Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao;' (212 bytes)
  511: 0x4052eb38 cls=Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao; (12 bytes)
JNI local reference table summary (512 entries):
   58 of Ljava/lang/Class; 212B (1 unique)
    1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 236B
   25 of Ljava/lang/Class; 284B (1 unique)
    1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 572B
  392 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (392 unique)
    1 of Ljava/lang/String; 36B
    1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 28B
    2 of [Ljava/lang/String; 92B (2 unique)
   31 of Lcom/project/storage/userdata/DataDao; 12B (1 unique)
Memory held directly by tracked refs is 12540 bytes
```

Any ideas as to why the overflow is happening?
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am quite convinced that you need to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` for each `NewStringUTF`, regardless of whether you do `DeleteLocalRef` afterwards.

Comment: Does it make sense? since I am not accessing a jstring from the vm but sending one to it... Would I have to create a pointer to the string and then call use that pointer to do the releaseStringUtfChars..

Comment: You only need to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` if you previously called `GetStringUTFChars()` to create a C-String from a Java-String. That isn't the case here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to delete the local refs immediately after use. Like this:

```
jstring string;
string = env->NewStringUTF(item->get_id().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,0,string);
env->DeleteLocalRef(string);
string = env->NewStringUTF(item->get_number().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,1,string);
env->DeleteLocalRef(string);
string = env->NewStringUTF(item->get_fullname().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,2,string);
env->DeleteLocalRef(string);
string = env->NewStringUTF(item->get_mf().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,3,string);
env->DeleteLocalRef(string);
string = env->NewStringUTF(item->get_dob().c_str());
env->SetObjectArrayElement( data,4,string);
env->DeleteLocalRef(string);
env->CallVoidMethod(dao, jsaveItem, data, jtype);
```

I'm not sure if GetObjectArrayElement() is returning the same localref or creating a new one. If it is creating a new one then that would explain why you are filling up the localref table.

Comment: I don't see how the system can get a new reference? you think that by getElementObject they return a copy of the pointer? not the original one?

Comment: Yes, it returns a copy of the pointer (actually it isn't just a pointer, it is a localref). See @jogabonito's answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

@Davids's answer is correct. You are running out of space in the local reference table since the references to the temporary strings you are creating using `NewStringUTF` are getting lost. If you look at your error message you can see

> 392 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (392 unique)

The references NewStringUTF objects you are creating are "anonymous" and will be lost. By deleting the reference to `data` you are only deleting the reference to the array. The strings will still be in memory till the function exits. I also feel that passing `emptyString` as an argument to `NewObjectArray` is superflous and NULL will do as well

Comment: Okay, will try it today and share results after!