# How to view JNI local reference table?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is there any way to see contents of the JNI local reference table?

I can see it if I got a crash when it's overflowed, via android LogCat, and there is a lot of info about referenced objects, unique instances etc. which helps to catch potential memory leaks.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, it might be that you get a JNI crash and would like to find out which line in your source the addresses in the stack trace correspond to, so does a look at the answer to [How to use addr2line in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android) help you?

Comment: @Raimo
No. If I got a crash i can see this table like in the question [Android NDK overflows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079912/android-ndk-overflows-dalvik-jni-local-reference-table)
I wonder, if I can view this reference table during normal work of my applcation.

Comment: @Why? What good would it do you? Are you going to execute different code based on its contents? I think what you are really looking for is `PushLocalFrame()` and `PopLocalFrame()`.

Comment: @EJP No, I want to check how my code works and improve it if I have a lot of unused local references - to prevent overflowing in future. Thx for Push/PopLocalFrame, but it's still not what I am searching for.

Comment: How exactly can you have unused local references? And if you can, how is Push/PopLocalFrame not an adequate solution?

Comment: @EJP For example I create a lot of jobjects in a cycle - they should freed by GC when become unreferenced, but it could take some time, so the table overflows. PopLocalFrame destroys all local objects, not only unreferenced objects.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer **CheckJNI**.

It can catch number of common error. For ICS CheckJNI is on by default if `debuggable="true"` in your `Manifest.xml`.

Thanks